# Symfony2|Doctrine2 - SQL to DQL: create a queryBuilder correctly in a repository, then call the query in a controller

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql, query-builder

I have this **SQl** request I use for a table in my Symfony project:

```
SELECT u.name, count(distinct o.id), count(distinct co.id)
            FROM `users` u
            LEFT OUTER JOIN orders o ON u.id = o.user_id
            LEFT OUTER JOIN cancelledOrders co ON o.id = co.order_id
            GROUP BY u.id
```

I modified this SQl request in order to have it in **DQL** like this:

```
SELECT u.name,
count(distinct o.id) AS ocnt,
count(distinct co.id) AS cocnt
FROM MyBundle:Users u
LEFT OUTER JOIN  MyBundle:Orders o WITH u.id = o.user
LEFT OUTER JOIN MyBundle:CancelledOrders co WITH o.id = co.order
GROUP BY u.id
```

The request works well. But I know it is not **advisable** to directly make a **DQL** request like this in a controller, *according to the symfonyBook*. I would like to make a **QueryBuilder** in a **repository** and **called** my **method** in my **controller correctly**. Do you know how to do this exactly ?

I try this in my **UsersRepository.php** :

```
public function resumeUsersOrders () {
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
                ->select('count(o.id)')
                ->addSelect('count(co.id)')
                ->from('MyBundle:Users', 'u')
                ->addFrom('MyBundle:Orders', 'o')
                ->addFrom('MyBundle:CancelledOrders', 'co')
                ->leftJoin('o.user','WITH', 'u.id = o.user')
                ->leftJoin('co.order', 'WITH', 'o.id = co.order')
                ->groupBy('p.id')
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult();
}
```

For now I do not know if it works really because i have an error from my controller when I try to launch my webpage:

> Undefined method 'resumeUsersOrders'. The method name must start with
>   either findBy or findOneBy! 500 Internal Server Error -
>   BadMethodCallException

And in my `controller`, I called the method like this:

```
public function indexUsersAction() {
    $user = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Users');
               ->resumeUsersorders();

return $this->render('MyBundle:MyFolder:indexUsers.html.twig', array('user' => $user ));
}
```

In my `twig` I display the result in an **html**  like this:

```
<table id="dataTablesUsers" class="table table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0">
     <thead>
         <tr>
             <th>Idt</th>
             <th>Name</th>
             <th>Orders'number</th>
             <th>Cancelled Orders'number</th>
             <th>Edit Action </th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
          {% for user in users%}
              <tr>
                  <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
                  <td>{{ user.name}}</td>
                  <td>{{ user.ocnt }}</td>
                  <td>{{ user.cocnt }}</td>
                  <td><a href="{{ path('edit', {'nom': users.name}) }}"><button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">Edit</button></a></td>
              </tr>
          {% endfor %}
     </tbody> 
  </table>
```

---

UPDATE

In fact the problem was that I wrote my annotations like this:

```
<?php

namespace My\Entity\Namespace;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="My\Repo\Namespace\RepoClass")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class MyEntity
{
    ...
}
```

Or the line `* @ORM\Entity` under  `@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="My\Repo\Namespace\RepoClass")` erase all before if I keep this annotation. I remove that, and the method is found by Symfony.

Now I have another error:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 210 near 'WITH GROUP BY': Error: 'WITH'
>   is already defined. 500 Internal Server Error - QueryException 1
>   linked Exception: QueryException »

This is my repository function in my repository class:

```
public function resumeUsersOrders () {
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
                ->select('count(o.id)')
                ->addSelect('count(co.id)')
                ->from('MyBundle:Orders', 'o')
                ->from('MyBundle:CancelledOrders', 'co')
                ->leftJoin('o.user','WITH', 'u.id = o.user')
                ->leftJoin('co.order', 'WITH', 'o.id = co.order')
                ->groupBy('p.id')
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult();
}
```

And my controller in order to call the methods:

```
public function indexUsersAction() {
    $user = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Users');
               ->resumeUsersorders();

return $this->render('MyBundle:MyFolder:indexUsers.html.twig', array('user' => $user ));
}
```

Someone could help?

Thank you.

Comment: What's the name of your method? queryCountBy or resumeUsersOrders? Because probably you have a typo, or at least you have it in here

Comment: @DonCallisto, sorry for the late, I have made a mistake whan I copied my code, I already make an update in my stackoverflow question. Thank you for the time you lose for looking my code. Now I have another problem with my `queryBuilder` method. Check my update.

Answer (score 1):

The error you're seeing is because you didn't tell Doctrine that **UsersRepository** is actually your repository class.

So it uses it's default **EntityRepository** class which doesn't have your method defined.

Assuming you're using annotation mapping you can do that like so:

```
<?php

namespace My\Entity\Namespace;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="My\Repo\Namespace\RepoClass")
 */
class MyEntity
{
}
```

If you're using some other mapping format like YAML or XML you can see how to do it in the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes).

Comment: +1 You're also calling method `queryCountBy` in your controller whereas your repository method is named `resumeUsersOrders`. There is also no need to call addFrom in your query building.

Comment: @Gildas, Sorry, my mistake when I copied on StackOverflow. In my code, everything is fine, the methods have the same name. Thank you for your comment. @Igor Pantović, I'm going to to try your suggestion, but indeed, this beginner mistake, I forgot to add the line `* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="My\Repo\Namespace\RepoClass")`v you mentionned in your answer.

Comment: @Igor Pantović, in fact I had already declare my repository, check my update. I just have to remove `@ORM\Entity` I wrote under the line `@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="My\Repo\Namespace\RepoClass")`. But i still have an error.